# How to I change the extents of a Euclidian Distance Raster?

Tags: raster, distance

I am calculating the Euclidean distance of a set of points.  The output raster truncates the resulting raster image to the farthest north, south, east, and west point.  I need the distances to extend past those points.  I have created another constant raster that is roughly the size of the area that I need.[image]

Comment: What GIS software are you using?

Comment: Euclidean Distance is an ArcGis tool but can also be an operation in GRASS, QGIS or other software package... If I assume ArcGis I would say have a look at your environment settings especially Output Extent, CellSize and Snap Raster and set *all three* to your constant raster, but that would only be if you were using ArcGis.

Comment: I am using ArcGIS.  By changing my environment settings I was able to get it to work.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Euclidean Distance is an ArcGis tool but can also be an operation in GRASS, QGIS or other software package... If I assume ArcGis I would say have a look at your environment settings especially Output Extent, CellSize and Snap Raster and set all three to your constant raster, but that would only be if you were using ArcGis. – Michael Miles-Stimson